# "Acomoda el número" OmegaUp

Tags: c++, array, algoritmos

estoy aprendiendo a programar y me he topado con un problema que no he podido resolver: [Enlace](https://omegaup.com/arena/problem/AcomodandoOMI#problems)

He tenido varios intentos, donde excedo el limite de tiempo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    int aux, value;
    int  count = 0;

    cin >> value;
    cin >> aux;

    for (int i = 1; i < value ; i++)
    {
        int temp;

        cin >> temp;

        if (temp < aux)
            count += 1;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Mi código funciona asi: En lugar de crear un arreglo y ordenarlo, leo la cantidad de números que voy a leer a continuación y leo mi numero principal `aux`. En el for, comparo si los siguientes números a leer, son menores que mi número principal `aux`, si es asi, incremento mi variable `count` en 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu principal problema es que, por temas de compatibilidad, los buffers de C y de C++ están sincronizados por defecto.

Esto implica que una lectura de `cin` tiene que actuar también sobre `stdin`, lo cual añade carga de trabajo adicional.

La solución es tan sencilla como utilizar [sync_with_stdio](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)

```
std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false);
```

Por otro lado, te piden **imprimir un resultado**, no devolverlo vía `return`:

```
std::cout << count;
return 0;
```